# How to share files to Airstash programmatically?

Tags: java, android

i'm android software developer, i want to share files to Airstash programmatially without open the Airstash+ application. is there any sdk available for android? please give me any suggestion.

Comment: Looks like an SDK for android is not available. But available on iOS http://support.airstash.com/forums/20898152

Answer (score 0):

AirStash is also a WebDAV server (also uses http streaming). You can use this standard to access folders & files, create/delete folders & files (rename and move is on the way--see AirStash on Facebook). There are many 3rd party apps that access AirStash utilizing this method.

Answer (score 0):

Recently purchased a RAVPower® FileHub and its great value really worth the money.  Main reason was that it is a simple and reliable product with a SD card slot and USB port to connect a multitude of different storage devices. It acts as both a router with the ability to bridge my home or business to access to the internet, and as a device you can add storage devices some external storage for my documents. All these it works great. Wish I would find this before cause it really a MUST.Besides, its 3000Amh external battery help my smartphone a lot when I am outing! It priced only $49.99 makes it more attractive!